# External display flickers on one of the Mac ports

Tags: display, usb, thunderbolt, hdmi

So I got a usb-c adapter/hub that gives me VGA, HDMI and some USB ports. If I connect it to one of my Pro's two ports, it works fine. If I connect it to the other, both VGA and HDMI start flickering. The port on the Mac itself is fine since I tried it with a different adapter.

Can anyone give me a hint on why such inconsistency might exist. Could it be because one port is USB 3.0 and the other is (in my understanding) USB 3.1?

**Update 1**: I have a Macbook Pro 13inch 2017 no touchbar and I used this dongle: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0749JXV6R/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0749JXV6R)

**Update 2** Just tried it with a different Macbook Pro (13inch, with touchbar), same issue persists. The hub only works with one of the ports as if the two ports are somehow different.

Comment: Without knowing which MacBook (Pro/Air) and what video adapter, it's going to be really difficult from this vantage point.  Please update with the details of your setup.

Answer (score 3):

The [13" MacBook Pro](https://www.apple.com/macbook-pro/specs/) has two Thunderbolt 3 ports with support for USB 3.1.  USB-C is the connector type.  There are no 3.0 ports at all.

[image]

The flickering you are experiencing sounds like a clock sync issue  ([TDMS clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#Version_comparison) for the display, not the clock that keeps system time).

First thing I would try is rebooting with the hub/dock connected to the port that's giving you trouble.  If the problem goes away, then you've narrowed down the problem.

If it remains, you may have a hardware issue.  Before taking it into Apple, however, it might be a good idea to try out a different video adapter.

Comment: So I tried rebooting but the issue persisted. However, if I use a normal USBC to HDMI cable (from CableCreation) it just works fine.

Comment: That's actually a DisplayPort to HDMI (a USB to HDMI would be an "active adapter and you would have a "box" at the HDMI end).  That adapter *may* have an issue with the clock signal or that TB port may have an issue.  I would get it checked by Apple right away while your warranty is still good.